# SMTP - No Subject?

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I can't seem to figure out why the Subject field is not filled out when the e-mail is sent in Gmail. The email_list.txt is a simple text file full of emails seperated on new lines. Here's my code:

---

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = "username@gmail.com"  
gmail_password = "******"

sent_from = gmail_user
file = open("email_list.txt", "r")
to = file.readlines() 
subject = "SUBJECT OF E-MAIL"  
body = "BODY OF E-MAIL"

email_text = """\  
From: %s  
To: %s  
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:  
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print("Email sent!")
except:  
    print("Error!")
```

Comment: Theres only so much i can do to help. The format `" ,".join(to)` is expanding to each name on a new line with commas at the end and a blank line between subject: and to: lines. Is that what you want

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the generated message? I'm guessing you have empty lines or perhaps DOS carriage returns left in the `To:` file.